# Using a Java EE Bean to Save a List of Form Data and print out data in a JSF XHTML DataTable

Tags: java, forms, jsf, jakarta-ee, xhtml

Here is how my application currently works.

1.User fills out a "Voter Registration" XHTML form.

2.When the user clicks submit, The values are saved through using a SessionScoped CDI Java-EE file.

Here are the contents of that file:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class VoterBean implements Serializable{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
 private String city;
 private String state;
 private String zip;
    private String phone;
    private String affil;

    public VoterBean(){

    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

 public String getCity(){
        return city;
    }

 public String getState(){
        return state;
    }

 public String getZip(){
        return zip;
    }


    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    public String getAffil(){
        return affil;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }


  public void setCity(String city){
        this.city = city;
    }

  public void setState(String state){
        this.state = state;
    }

  public void setZip(String zip){
        this.zip = zip;
    }   

    public void setPhone(String phone){
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public void setAffil(String affil){
        this.affil = affil;
    }


}
```

3.The user is given a summary of the values he/she filled in. The user is asked if the values are currently ok or not. If the user clicks "No" the user is taken back to the Registraiton form to be able to change his/her values.

Now the problem is when they click "Yes".

I have two issues:

Issue #1:

I want to create a Bean file where after a user clicks "Yes" the form information is saved as a List. So if multiple people finish the Registration process there should be multiple lists with their information.

I would think that I would grab the information currently stored in the Java-EE bean file above and transport it to another Java EE file to create the lists. The question is how would I make a list of all that information and keep it saved?

Issue #2

After the user clicks "Yes", he/she will be taken to a page that should show all the information in a JSF XHTML DataTable.

From what I read about JSF files  to insantiate a Datable in JSF XHTML it goes like this

```
<h:dataTable value="#{order.orderList}" var="o"
styleClass="order-table"
headerClass="order-table-header"
rowClasses="order-table-odd-row,order-table-even-row">

</h:dataTable>
```

Assuming I had a Java-EE file called "Order" and a List variable called "orderList" this data Table would get the values in that List varable and print each of the different Lists in separate rows?

Any tips would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest for that, to use an alternative way to store the registration informations of each person, **through** an independant bean called `Person.java`, that you instanciate in your managed bean. The new bean will contain the registration informations you're putting in the managed bean. This way, you'd not use the list except for displaying purpose :

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;
    private String phone;
    private String affil;

    public Person(){ }

    // getters/setters

}
```

Now, one managed bean is enough to do all the stuff, it should look like in the end something like this :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class VoterBean implements Serializable{

     private Person person = new Person();
     private List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<Person>();

     public VoterBean(){
     }

     public List<Person> getPersonsList() {
          return personsList;
     }

     public String saveRegistration(){
         personsList.add(person);
         return "registrationsList";  // navigation to the registration list page after each complete registration process (click save button)
     }

}
```

in the display page, call the list by :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{voterBean.personsList}" var="p" ... >
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```